# Control the compression level when writing Parquet files using Polars in Rust

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, compression, parquet, rust-polars

I found that by default polars' output Parquet files are around 35% larger than Parquet files output by Spark (on the same data). Spark uses snappy for compression by default and it doesn't help if I switch ParquetCompression to snappy in polars. I wonder is this due to polars use a more conservative compression ratio? Is there any way to control the compression level of Parquet files in polars? I checked the doc of polars, it seems that only Zstd accept a ZstdLevel (not even sure whether it is compression level).

Below is my code to write a DataFrame to a Parquet file using the snappy compression.

```
let f = File::create("j.parquet").expect("Unable to create the file j.parquet!");
let mut bfw = BufWriter::new(f);
let pw = ParquetWriter::new(bfw).with_compression(ParquetCompression::Snappy); 
pw.finish(&mut df);
```

Comment: And Python pandas (which leverages pyarrow) outputs Parquet files which have similar sizes as output Parquet files from Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not (yet) possible in `rust polars`. It will likely be in next release of `arrow2` and then we can implement it in polars as well.

If you want that functionality in `python polars` you can leverage `pyarrow` for this purpose. `polars` has zero copy interop with `pyarrow`.